# Is it possible to encrypt an email for two keys but the same email?

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail, openpgp

I started using Enigmail with Thunderbird to encrypt and sign my mails. It works fine with my brother and some other people.

Yesterday I got a reply from someone with whom I did communicate via encrypted mail that he couldn't decrypt my mail. He switched from Mailvelope to Thunderbird and had a new Key-Pair and thus could only decrypt it with one of the two keys (as is expected).

Is there a way to encrypt it in such a way that he can decrypt it with both his private keys (either with Enigmail or Mailvelope)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Some Theory: Hybrid Cryptography Systems

OpenPGP uses a hybrid cryptography approach: symmetric encryption with the so-called "session key" for encrypting the message itself, and then encrypting the session key with public/private key cryptography, once for each recipient. This is on one hand a performance requirement (public/private key cryptography is much slower than symmetric cryptography), but also allows to encrypt to multiple recipients without sending the whole encrypted message multiple times (only the small session key is encrypted multiple times).

### Using Multiple Recipients

When using GnuPG on the command line, multiple recipients can be used through passing the `--recipient` option multiple times. At least Enigmail for Thunderbird (I never used Mailvelope) also provides this ability, but it to be enabled in the expert options before. Open the *Enigmail*  menu, and click *Preferences*. Now, click *Display Expert Settings and Menus*, go to the *Key Selection*  tab and enable *Always (also) Manually*.

In future, whenever encrypting mails, Enigmail will show a window with all available public keys to select from.

### Better Use Multiple Mail Addresses or Share the Key

Anyway: As this involves quite some hassle, it might be more reasonable your communication partner sticks with a single key per mail address. Keys can be exported and shared among computers. If he has special security requirements, he should use dedicated mail addresses instead. OpenPGP and its implementations do not really consider the use case "single mail address, but multiple devices with different keys".